# Selenium in Python: button element seems to vanish after interacting with reCAPTCHA. wha?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, recaptcha

I'm trying to interact with a page that requires entry of a username and a passcode, then requires a click on a reCAPTCHA and then a click on a login button. Entry of the username and passcode and clicking on the reCAPTCHA work fine, but after interacting with the reCAPTCHA, the login button element seems to be unfindable by Selenium. The thing is, the login button element is easily found by Selenium *before* interacting reCAPTCHA. What's going on?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://localbitcoins.com/accounts/login/")
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
element.send_keys("username")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element.send_keys("passcode")
time.sleep(1)
# reCAPTCHA
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "google.com/recaptcha")]')))
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
# login button
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Login')]")
elements[0].click()
```

Comment: Just a hunch, you may have to "reactivate" (or whatever selenium calls it) the main html page (or iframe maybe?) that has the login button.

Comment: @SuperStew Hey, thanks for that. You were quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to handle "Login" button you have to switch back from `iframe` after interacting with it:

```
# reCAPTCHA
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "google.com/recaptcha")]')))
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor"))).click()

# Switch to default content
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# login button
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Login')]")
elements[0].click()
```

P.S. Note that there is no need to use `time.sleep(1)` before `wait(driver, 10)`. If you need more time to wait - just increase timeout, e.g. `wait(driver, 15)`

Comment: Great, thanks very much for that solution. I hadn't considered the need to switch between frames.